# Is there cross-platform method to encode a string into another string without any whitespaces and then decode it back?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, encoding

I am trying to pass a block of text to a system I do not own, which will pass the data to a system I do own.

Unfortunately, when the first system talks to the second system, it uses a TSV format. Thus, I wonder if there's a convenient way to take my block of text and encode it in an ASCII format without any kind of whitespace (mostly newlines and tabs, of course), and then later decode it.

When I'm doing the encoding, I'm working in C#. When I'm doing the decoding, I'm working in Javascript.

I realize that I can write my own code to essentially "manually" perform the encoding and decoding by creating my own scheme, but I wonder if there already exists one for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

One option which would blow up the size of your data but be *really* simple to implement: UTF-8 encode all the text, base64-encode that:

```
byte[] utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64(utf);
```

That won't contain any whitespace, and can be converted back. It'll be significantly larger than the original string, and unreadable... but it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) or [Uri.EscapeDataString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx), which would [percent-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) any whitespace in the passed in text (as well as other special characters, which means the encoded text may be much larger than the original).

On the javascript side you could then use [decodeURIComponent(string)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp) to decode it back to the original text.